# vrule align with top of the text using multicols

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, rules

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2pt}
%\setlength{\multicolsep}{-10pt}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I would like to align `rule` with top of the text. (see the example image).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multicols` environment uses `\topskip` before typesetting the columns. Setting `topskip=0pt` is a (possible) solution.

Modifying `\multicolsep` does only affect the total spacing above `multicols` environment, but not the internal skip.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{3}
\topskip=0pt
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the top of the multicols its working fine. How to control in the bottom?

Comment: @Balaji: You did **not** write anything about the bottom, did you?

Comment: Yes. I have need in the bottom also. Please suggest.

Comment: @Balaji: That's changing the question

Comment: @Balaji: Sigh... you should not change the question afterwards. It is up to you to post a clear question right from the start, not changing it in the end such that a posted solution becomes useless. This is **not** ok!